# Set sticky posts schedule (Automatic)

Tags: sticky-post

**EDIT:**
It is currently working when I set a sticky post and set it's date at 07/07/2016.
My code so far:
I've added this to change the post date of the post when it become sticky :

```
//        Update post timestamp
$newdate = current_time('mysql');
        $my_post = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_date' => $newdate
        );
        wp_update_post($my_post);
//        Update post timestamp
```

And also this to unstick the post if it is sticky and older than 7 days :

```
function deleteOldStickies($post_id, $postDate) {
    $postDate = strtotime($postDate);
    $currentTime = strtotime(time());
    $expire = $currentTime + strtotime('-1 day');
    if ($postDate < $expire && is_sticky()) {
        unstick_post($post_id);
        echo 'Обявата е изтекла!';
    }
}
```

In content.php I call the function as :

```
<?php echo deleteOldStickies($post->ID, $post->post_date); ?>
```

My further question from the info above is - am I missing something important, will it work good in live enviroment?

Comment: Not valid enough for a answer, but in [this plugin](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/scheduled-unsticky/tags/0.4/class-scheduled-unsticky.php) you find all relevant information to use cron and the right hooks to create a solution.

Comment: Hi @bueltge , thanks for your answer, can you check my updated question, please? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I got it working this is the code I used, I am not sure if it is the best practice but it certainly works.

In functions.php where I make the posts sticky from the front-end I added this to update the post_date to today so I can have control over the sticky period:

```
$newdate = current_time('mysql');
$my_post = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_date' => $newdate
);
wp_update_post($my_post);
```

In functions.php (I used -1 day for testing purpose, if you type -7 days on the $expire variable it will unstick stickyposts older than 7 days.

```
//Delete Old Stickies START
function deleteOldStickies($post_id, $postDate) {
    $postDate = strtotime($postDate);
    $expire = strtotime('-1 day') + get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600;
    if ($postDate < $expire && is_sticky()) {
        unstick_post($post_id);
    }
}

//Delete Old Stickies END
```

In the loop :

```
<?php echo deleteOldStickies($post->ID, $post->post_date); ?>
```